# Qt emit signal and continue execution

Tags: qt, signals

I have something like that:

**Prueba.h**

```
#include <QObject>
class Prueba:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
 private:
     bool waiting;
 public:
     Prueba();
     void test();
     void fin();
 signals:
     void comenzo();
};
```

**Prueba.cpp**

```
#include "prueba.h"
#include <QDebug>

Prueba::Prueba()
{
    waiting=true;
}

void Prueba::test()
{
    qDebug()<<"Comenzando";
    emit(comenzo());
    while(waiting) {
        qDebug()<<"Esperando";
    }
    qDebug()<<"Termino";
}

void Prueba::fin()
{
    waiting=false;
}
```

**Principal.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include "prueba.h"
class Principal:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
 private:
     Prueba * prueba;
 public:
     Principal();
 private slots:
     void processSignal();
};
```

**Principal.cpp**

```
#include <QDebug>

Principal::Principal()
{
    prueba=new Prueba();
    connect(prueba,SIGNAL(comenzo()),SLOT(processSignal()));
    prueba->test();
}

void Principal::processSignal()
{
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        qDebug()<<"Algo";
    }
    prueba->fin();
}
```

When I call prueba->test(), and it emit the signal "comenzo", Principal::proccessSignal is completely executed, and never enters to the cycle "while(waiting)". What I need to do for that the code inside the loop is executed?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your signal connection. By default Qt will execute your signal as a direct call to the slot the objects are in the same thread as you can see here:

```
QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(
    const QObject * sender, const char * signal, 
    const char * method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection) const
```

See Qt::ConnectionType here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum

So if you use

```
Qt::QueuedConnection
```

in your signal connection

```
connect(prueba,SIGNAL(comenzo()),SLOT(processSignal()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

It should work as expected. See

> The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.